# Windows - Global Zoom Tool That Doesn't Hijack Mouse Cursor

Tags: windows, utility

Looking for a global zoom tool ( in other words - system wide -applying to whatever is on the screen ) that doesn't require mouse interaction.

The purpose of said tool is to allow me to still work with my mouse while zoomed in ( just like I would zoom in in Photoshop or Illustrator ), so that is the only requirement however it is achieved. Hotkey access would be nice, and it would be great if it was lightweight as well.   But those are good properties for any application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows magnifier, (supplied by default since Win 3.11 IIRC), is triggered with the Windows and `+` keys and then zooms in 100% by default for each press - it zooms back out with the windows and `-` keys.

Even better if your mouse pointer gets near to the edge of your screen(s) it auto scrolls the magnifier by default.

Comment: That's funny.  Why do tools like zooming by Sysinternals even exist?

Comment: I just find the window and icon in the taskbar very annoying...